# java - spring mvc @RequestMapping produces multiple formats

Tags: java, spring-mvc

I'm working on a java spring mvc application. I have a method in my controller that responsible for producing image:

```
 @RequestMapping(value = "/view", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = "image/jpg")
public void viewImage(HttpServletResponse response, HttpServletRequest request) throws Exception
```

This works fine. But I have a problem now. The produced images may have 3 formats jpg, jpeg and png. Therefore I need several `produces` attribute in the `@RequestMapping`. Is there any way to do this? For example, something like this: `produces = "image/jpg, image/jpeg, image/png"`

Answer (score 7):

You can have multiple mime types in produces, something like

`produces={"image/jpg, image/jpeg, image/png"}`

Now in order for the framework to know to which mimeType to resolve, you need to either add a Path or Parameter, or Accept header to the request (the so called PPA strategy). Read more at [content negotiation](https://spring.io/blog/2013/05/11/content-negotiation-using-spring-mvc)

Answer (score 7):

as of the newer versions of `Spring`, it's nicer to implement like so :

```
produces = {MediaType.IMAGE_JPEG_VALUE, MediaType.IMAGE_PNG_VALUE, MediaType.IMAGE_GIF_VALUE}
```

Answer (score 2):

In your case, the `produces` field does not matter since the method returns `void`. Seems to be writing image to the output stream. You can set the response header with the required image format.
**E.g.:**

```
response.setContentType("image/jpeg");
```

Answer (score 1):

I found it. From [this link](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/RequestMapping.html#produces--), `produces` attribute can have a string array. So I can have this:

```
producess = {"image/jpg", "image/jpeg", "image/png"}
```